# Map values from a list of values in one of the dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, knime

the following situation:
[image]

Equipment is a pandas series and far as I know (split response said so).
What I like to do is: If the value ABS shows up, insert into the corresponding column ABS 1, if the value is in Equipment or 0, the value is not in equipment - or copy ABS into that corresponding field and if not, leave it as it is.

I used something similiar, but it doesn't work well:

```
df_copy.loc[df_copy['col2']=='str1', 'col4'] = df_copy['col3']
```

The next thing is, I have over 90 values/columns so doing this for all would be very time consuming.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks and have a nice one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please explain better what you are trying to do. If "equipment" contains ABS then the ABS column should be 1 and if not it should be 0?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you have in mind?:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'equipment': {'0': ['ABS',  'ABS' , 'Android Auto'],
                              '1': ['ABS', 'abstand']}})
df = pd.get_dummies(df.equipment.explode()).groupby(level=0).agg(sum)
df

   ABS  Android Auto  abstand
0    2             1        0
1    1             0        1
```

Comment: Hello gtomer, thank you for your answer. To go more into detail.

In my Dataframe I have the following Object called Equipment (Columnname):


`Row0      ABS, Abstandstempomat, Android Auto, Antriebss...


Row1      ABS, Abstandstempomat, Android Auto, Antriebss...`

Comment: Hello gtomer, thank you for your answer. To go more into detail.

In my Dataframe I have the following Object called Equipment (Columnname):
<br>
`Row0      ABS, Abstandstempomat, Android Auto, Antriebss...</br><br>
Row1      ABS, Abstandstempomat, Android Auto, Antriebss...`<br>

Comment: Hello gtomer, thank you for your answer. To go more into detail. And sorry for my troubles with editing.

In my Dataframe I have the following Object called Equipment (Columnname):
`Row0      ABS, Abstandstempomat, Android Auto, Antriebss...
Row1      ABS, Abstandstempomat, Android Auto, Antriebss...¸

The Key is Row0 to RowN. In my Dataframe I have also a Column called ABS. Now, when the value ABS is found in Equipment.RowN I want in the field of Column ABS a 1, if ABS is not found in Equipment.RowN, then I like to add and 0 to this field in the column.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: I do not understand your expected output. Please post in your question a short sample of your data and expected output

Comment: hello gtomer, because I use this Python Script in Knime, I had an error in the code with two Dataframes. Your Code Example is working, but I have one last question. If there is a thrid or fourth Row with ABC duplicate Columns are created. So I noticed that in one column there was a 0 and in the duplicate column the 1 - the value in the duplicate colum is correct, do you know how to handle this?

Comment: Please explain better your problem

Comment: hello @gtomer, thank you for your patience. my problem ist, that `explode()` creates duplicate columns.

Comment: In my answer above it didn't... There is only one ABS column although appears twice

Comment: I also changed the answer to include two ABS in the same list and it still does not contain dups

Comment: I use this Python Script in KNIME. I needed to adapt the code a bit.
```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(input_table_1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(input_table_1)
#df['index'] = df.index
#df_2['index'] = df_2.index

df = pd.DataFrame(df.equipment.str.split(','))
df_2 = pd.get_dummies(df.explode('equipment')).groupby(level=0).agg(sum)

output_table_1 = pd.merge(df, df_2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```
When I use your code, the first ABS is not recognized. So I added AAA in front, and now the first ABS is part of the sum.

Comment: I cannot help before seeing sample of the data

Comment: Because I was not able to reproduce it in a comment, I posted a new Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76916578/pandas-dataframe-object-count-occurrence-of-values-and-and-group-in-columns